# ListView Insert new item on TAB

Tags: wpf, listview, keydown

Having a WPF ListView with items bound to a data object and represented by editors (Text, DateTime, etc.). I would like to be able to insert a new item when the users is in the last editor at the last item and presses TAB. Then after set input focus to the first editor of the newly added item.

Thus far I have this:

```
private Boolean _tabAddedNewSpec = false;
private void OnBaseEditKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_tabAddedNewSpec)
    {

        if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
            if (this.listview.SelectedItem == this.listview.Items[this.listview.Items.Count - 1])
                {
                    this.AddSpec();

                    // No further tabbing out of this control, we manage it ourselves in this special case...
                    e.Handled = true;
                    _tabAddedNewSpec = true;

                    // Select last item (is NEW one)
                    this.listview.SelectedItem = this.listview.Items[this.listview.Items.Count - 1];

                }
    }
}
private void OnBaseEditKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (_tabAddedNewSpec)
    {
        ((BaseEdit)sender).MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        _tabAddedNewSpec = false;
    }
}
```

This code almost does the trick. But, I don't allow that a spec (specification) is added when there are other specs that contain validation errors (on the business object). The problem is that when pressing TAB the editvalue on the last editor isn't yet passed to the business object. Then when calling this.AddSpec() results in nothing because it detects that there are still errors. Follow me still...

And by the way, this solution seems pretty dirty to me. Anybody good advice? Very welcome!

Comment: Just curious why arent you using WPF DataGrid? It allows a nice AddNewRow feature that can be masked to not allow if there are validation errors... It also allows text columns, combobox columns, checkbox columns, and even template ones.... validation is also nicely suported....

Comment: ehhh... we started with a DevExpress DataGrid for WPF. But we had some "problems" with the visual design of it. So started to look at self-made solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned before, the solution nearly did the trick. With first updating the binding of the active control the desired solution was produced. Using this code:

```
BindingExpression bindingExpression = ((BaseEdit)sender).GetBindingExpression(TextEdit.TextProperty);

if (bindingExpression != null)
  bindingExpression.UpdateSource();
```